# EF code-first PluralizingTableNameConvention for ONE DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

How do I toggle this convention `PluralizingTableNameConvention` for only a single table/DbSet? As far as I can tell, I can only do this to all the `DbSets` for a given `DbContext`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have only one entity which is mapped to a table that is not pluralizeed then you can remove the `PluralizingTableNameConvention` and manually configure the table name of the entity.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Items");
    }
 }
```

Or if it is the otherway around

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item");
    }
 }
```